# Rails how to create different views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create different view modes. Like a visitor can choose list or box view.

Comment: I'm asking for help also in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-to-manage-different-views

Comment: [and the clean solution finally arrived!](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-to-manage-different-views/10319#10319)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much these views are similar, what I would do is to create partials for each view and then in the main view I call the right one depending on the property. Say you have a function in `application_helper` `which_view` in your `index` you can write something like this:

```
<!-- your index -->
<%= render which_view == :box ? 'index_box' : 'Index_list' %>
```

I prefer the previous, but if you have few changes you can go for something like:

```
<% if session[:view_type] == 'box' %>

  <!-- box content -->

<% else %>

  <!-- list content -->

<% end %>
```

** EDIT **

make the action:

```
  # application_controller.rb
  def set_view_type # TODO: refactor
    session[:view_type] = params[:view_type]
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

set your routes:

```
  # routes.rb
  match '/set_view_type' => 'application#set_view_type', :as => :set_view_type
```

write your form:

```
  <!-- _view_type_selection.html.erb -->
  <%= form_tag set_view_type_path do %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :view_type, :box, session[:view_type] == 'box' %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :view_type, :list, session[:view_type] == 'list' %>

    <%= submit_tag 'select' %>

  <% end %>
```

Not best practice but it works!

Comment: How to create the helper method ?

Answer (score 1):

I almost agree with ecoologic. Instead of second solution i would use something like case statement in controller which decides what template should be rendered.

> How to create the helper method ?

Add it into `<controller_name>_helper` file

Comment: Ah yes! this is better, you avoid to render the switcher that renders the partials! - Maybe you have a good idea on how to store the value, I don't like it very much

Comment: I don't know whole Rails beginner's idea, but instead of storing it, i would rather see it in url. So if i send a link for some interesting page, it looks same as on my screen and i can navigate recipient on that page. Or i can send that link directly with anchor, which could be in one layout, byt it does not in another. It's also better for bookmarking, etc...

I dont know any english example but look for this http://tv.seznam.cz/radkovy-program and this http://tv.seznam.cz/sloupcovy-program . I can send one of these links and say "Look at the second line/column"

Comment: I understand your pov, I personally don't like to store params in url, but thinking about a guest option it makes perfectly sense